# I am having trouble handling external files | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I have help.js file where I require all other commands so that I can have access to their usage,
This is my help.js codes:

```
//Here is how I require all other commands...
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');


//If i removed this from here...
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync('./commands/');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(`./commands/${folder}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const command = require(`../${folder}/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    }
}
//To here... the syntax is now defined on ban.js...


module.exports = {
  name: 'help',
  syntax: {
    syntax: { //I will use this if for example a command has invalid syntax
        color: 0xeb4034,
        title: 'Oops!',
        description: 'Looks like your syntax is invalid, see\n`?help {command}` for more description.'
    }, 
  }
  execute: async function(message, args) {
    //Here I call the ban usage
    switch (args[0]) {
      case 'ban':
        let { usage } = client.commands.get('ban');
        return message.channel.send({ embed: usage }); //This worked
    }
    
    More codes...
  }
```

But suddenly if I call the syntax in help.js from other file... it is undefined, but if I hover it, it's showing the value of the syntax,
Heres my ban.js codes:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { syntax } = require('../Global/help');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    usage: {
        color: 0x1e90ff,
        title: 'Ban',
        description: '`Usage:` {prefix}ban user time {optional reason}\n`Example:` ?ban <@message.author.tag> 1h/1m/1s Bad dude'
    },
    execute: async function(message, args) {
        //If I hover on the syntax, it is showing the value, but the result is undefined...
        console.log(syntax); //Shows undefined
        if (args.length < 1) return message.channel.send({ embed: syntax }); //Made an error
    }
}
```

[image]

This is how my files and folders are setup

How do I fix this?

Edit: I found the solution, its not running the code above the module.exports of ban.js so I made a function that returns the syntax

Comment: try to use it as ```syntax.syntax```

Comment: .Same  output :/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't constructed your client properly

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
intents: ["GUILDS","GUILD_MEMBERS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]
});
```